# How to load timezone files with timezone-js without Fleegix.js?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I want to use timezone-js in my app, but I'm not Fleegix.js, which "just works". The readme says to look in the spec file for an example, but it looks like that uses Node.js stuff. Is there a way to make a load for Jquery or just raw JS or something?

Answer (score 0):

I got confused on those docs also.  It's not quite clear, but jQuery support is already built in.  You just have to set `async` to `false` to get it to work.  Not sure why - since ajax is async anyway - but that's the flag to set to get it to work with jQuery.  No other wireup is needed.

```
timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = 'scripts/tz';
timezoneJS.timezone.init({ async: false });
```

Also - there are other libraries that do the same thing.  You may find one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824) more appealing.

Comment: I get this error (which is the same as without async: `Error: Please use the Fleegix.js XHR module, jQuery ajax, Zepto ajax, or define your own transport mechanism for downloading zone files.`. I do have jquery loaded, so I'm not sure why this is happening. I'll check out one of the other libraries too.

Comment: Basically, all I'm trying to do is get the current user's time zone in "America/Chicago" format via javascript. I'm not even sure any of these libraries do that.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll have to dig deeper then.  I thought that was all I had to do.  You might want to look at walltime-js.  nice writeup here: http://engineering.sproutsocial.com/2013/02/javascript-time-zone-conversion-with-walltime/